# csrf_token displayed as a URL parameter

Tags: security, http-token-authentication

Is it okay that a website displays the csrf_token as a URL parameter? I have a feeling that I shouldn't be able to see it, but I am no quite sure. If someone can clear this up a bit, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, It's not acceptable.

Passing tokens in URLs isn't normally an acceptable solution. Actually it's 
in some cases considered a **vulnerability**.

What if the Website not running under **HTTPS**?

What if it's running under **HTTPS** but **HSTS** isn't enabled on the server? Then **SSL-Stripping** techniques would be possible and other **MITM** attacks.

Even if it's running under **HTTPS** and **HSTS** is enabled that won't solve the issue.

The token could be exposed in:

- Referer Header
- Web Logs
- Shared Systems
- Browser History
- Browser Cache

For more information refer to:

[Information exposure through query strings in url](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url)

[OWASP CSRF Cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have tried to re-generate the problem on that site. It happens every time I change my profile picture, possibly every time the site sends a POST request. Do you think it's worth reporting to the site?

Answer (score 2):

The typical characteristics of a CSRF Token are as follows:

-Unique per user session
 - Large random value
 - Generated by a cryptographically secure random number generator

CSRF tokens in GET requests are potentially leaked at several locations: browser history, HTTP log files, network appliances that make a point to log the first line of an HTTP request, and Referer headers if the protected site links to an external site so it is not recommended.